# evento onchange do select

Tags: javascript

Tenho um programa PHP que no primeiro select retorna os diretórios do meu raiz(fiz em PHP), porem no evento onchange desse select quero povoar o outro select com os subdiretorios do primeiro e pelo que pesquisei só da pra fazer isso com javascript. Que funcao devo usar que retorne esses sub diretorios? Cada vez que seleciono um diretorio do primeiro retorna os subs no segundo.

Selecione um diretório:
                
                    $pastas";
                        $i++;
                    }
                    ?>
                
            
            
                Selecione um mes:
                
                    $pastas";
                        $i++;
                    }
                    ?>
                
            
        
        OK

Comment: Olá Sonia, mostre para nós o que você já tentou em forma de código. Tente expor como você obtém essa lista de diretórios e subdiretórios. Ela é estática(não variável) ou dinâmica. A busca dos subdiretórios é feita de forma assíncrona ou os valores já foram previamente carregados? tente nos da mais informação.

Comment: Olá Sonia! Dá uma olhada nas perguntas que marquei como duplicadas. Se ainda tiveres duvidas tenta ser mais específica na próxima pergunta sobre que parte tens dificuldade. E bem-vinda!